# Create new dataframe by applying 2D mask on another DataFrame with the same shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a fast and easy way to create a new data frame based on a masked dataframe and a dataframe with values:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[False, True],[True, False],[False, True], [False, False]] )

    0       1   
0   False   True
1   True    False
2   False   True
3   False   False

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6], [7, 8]] )

    0   1
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6
3   7   8
```

The result I want is a new dataframe that only contains the values masked TRUE:

```
    0   1
0   3   2
1   NaN 6
```

Comment: The output doesn't really make sense, why are there only 2 rows in the output? And why is 3 now associated with a different index than before?

Comment: why the 1st and 2nd result rows must be collapsed?

Comment: It's a new dataframe and the index is new, the index in the new dataframe represent number of occurrences in the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like there are two requests in this question:

1. mask values that we don't want, and
2. collapse rows so that the result is dense (no NaNs in between rows except the last ones)

To do the first one, use `df.where`. To do the second one, we need to `stack` first to eliminate NaNs, then reset the index of each column so that we can re-assign the non-null values to a new dense row when we `unstack` the output.

```
(df_2.where(df_1)
     .stack()
     .groupby(level=1)
     .apply(lambda d: d.reset_index(drop=True))
     .unstack(0))

     0    1
0  3.0  2.0
1  NaN  6.0
```

---

If performance is important, here's another attempt that doesn't involve `(un)stacking`:

```
m = df_2.where(df_1)
pd.DataFrame([m[c].to_numpy()[m[c].notna()] for c in m.columns]).T

     0    1
0  3.0  2.0
1  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: A nice solution but slow with large dataframes.

Comment: @Jonas how large?

Comment: Not very (3853, 272) but it need to do it many times and therefore performance is important.

Comment: @Jonas i added an alternative that doesn't involve stacking, let me know how that does?

Comment: Much faster! But for some reason it works on the test data but not on the real data. Need to investigate. Will be back!

Comment: Error on my side!

Comment: @Jonas hmm, not sure what's missing, can you create some test data that reproduces the bug? Open a new question and let me know, will try to help.

Comment: I had made an error with the input data, works fine!

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to apply the mask on the frame, but I believe it doesn't apply in your case. If I would like to get output like you posted, I would go for with concat and for loop. Something like this:

```
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[False, True],[True, False],[False, True], [False, False]] )
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6], [7, 8]] )
temp_arr = []
for col in df_2.columns:
    mask = df_1[col].values
    temp_df = df_2.loc[mask, col].reset_index(drop=True)
    temp_arr.append(temp_df)
print(temp_arr)
pd.concat(temp_arr,axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

With this you should get what you want.

Comment: Works, but slow with large dataframes. It might be the only possible solution to loop through every column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause of dataframe,

Use boolean indexing to filter df_2 based on df_1 mask and Drop rows where all values are NaN

`result = df_2.where(df_1)`

`result = result.dropna(how='all')`

`print (result)`

gives

```
     0    1
0  NaN  2.0
1  3.0  NaN
2  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: this is not what the OP is expecting though, is it?

Comment: Correct, it's close but we are not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you're doing something rather confusing to me. I can't comprehend the result you were looking for in the last code snippet, because it seems like some rows are merged arbitrarily. All that being said, maybe this helps:

```py
# given df_1 and df_2
df3 = df_1 * df_2 # to only keep the `True` values
df3.loc[(df3!=0).any(axis=1)] # to discard rows that are completely zeros
```

You should get something like:

```bash
   0  1
0  0  2
1  3  0
2  0  6
```

Comment: this is also not what the OP is expecting as there are 3 rows in the output instead of 2